# For what values of $c$ is $\sin (x+y) = c$ a smooth curve? Asked

Tags: smooth-manifolds, curves

Calculating the derivative, it's onto as long as $c$ isn't 1 or -1.

But when c = 1 or -1, is it still a smooth curve?

EDIT: I wrote c = 0 for some stupid reason

Comment: Isn't the curve essentially $y=-x \pmod \pi$ for $c=0$?

Comment: I'd be more worried about $c=\pm 1$ than $c=0$.

Comment: Oh you're right, i don't know why i wrote c =0. Then how do I check for c =1 or -1?

Answer (score 0):

It is a bunch of parallel lines, all of slope $-1$.  When $c$ reaches $\pm1$, the lines collide in pairs; as $c$ passes $-1$ or $1$, they disappear.
So they are always smooth, if they exist.